# WPF using PRISM and WCF - how to implement multiple views that connect to WCF services?

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm, prism

I am implementing a WPF client application in MVVM architecture using PRISM (I am new to PRISM).

The WPF application has 3 main regions :

- Left Region
- Right Region
- Side Region

The left region has a view with a 'Fetch Button', that when pressed should connect to a 'FETCH' WCF service, fetch items, disconnect from the service and present the items in the view.

The right region has a view with no buttons. This view should connect every 10 minutes to the 'POLL' WCF service, fetch items, disconnect from the service and present the items in the view.

The side region has a view with no buttons. This view should connect to the 'NOTIFICATIONS' WCF service, **and stay connected to it during the whole application life cycle**. It should receive callbacks from the service, that should be presented in the Side view.

Here is an [image](http://s11.postimage.org/xfjheqc0h/SO_Question_4.png) showing what it should look like:

[image]

**Questions :**

1. What should I pass on to the constructor of the 'FETCH MODULE' that includes the 'Fetch View' ? should it be the service itself or should it be some channel factory ? I think it should be some kind of channel factory, because the connection to the 'Fetch WCF Service' needs to be initiated every time the user pressed the 'fetch' button.
2. Same question goes for the 'POLL MODULE'.
3. Regarding the 'NOTIFICATIONS MODULE' - should I pass a Singleton instance of the 'Notification Service Client' ? (since the application needs to open only one client to the service, and it should stay connected all the time)
4. In order to avoid the 'Notifications' client faulting because of a timeout, I need to implement some sort of 'heartbeat', that will call a stub method on the 'Notifications' WCFservice, so that it doesn't timeout. Where should I place the code for the heartbeat ? should it be in the 'NOTIFICATIONS MODULE' ? who should initiate it ? (I believe it should run in some sort of background thread)
5. I am currently using MEF, and I don't really know what I am doing (I decorated the views with [Export] and the [ViewModel] setter with [Import] etc, but I still don't understand how I control who gets loaded and when). In addition - I don't understand how the Dependency Injection works in MEF. What are the differences between using 'MEF Bootstrapper' and 'Unity Bootstrapper' ?
6. I have seen some people use MEF and just use [Import] and [Export] attributes, and some people that inherit their modules from 'IModule' and implement 'InitializeModule' with EventAggreagator, Container and RegionManager. What are the differences between these approaches, and when should you use each approach ?
7. Do you recommend using the 'Add Service Reference...' or to manually create an 'IChannelFactory' ? (PROs \ CONs)
8. Should the service clients be part of the Modules or part of the Infrastructure ?
9. I have searched a lot on the internet for samples of WPF+PRISM+WCF and could not find any good samples I can use, so I can understand how to inject the services into my view-models. Can anyone offer any examples \ sample links ?

Following 4 questions are a **tough cookie:**

1. All 3 WCF services I have mentioned use the same 'Username+Password' authentication method, which means I need to pop-up a 'Login' window when the application loads. What is the best practice for doing such a thing in PRISM and MVVM ? Should the 'Login' window replace the 'Shell' window ? (I don't think so, so what should it be ?)
2. When the user enters the username+password - Should I try to connect to just the first service, and if it succeeds - disconnect from it and close the 'Login' view (meaning, I assume that the connection will succeed with the other services).
3. Where could I store the username+password the user has entered, so that the application can keep on reconnecting to the services without requesting the user to provide the credentials each time ?
4. What do you advise should be the approach I take if for some reason - one of the modules tries to connect to one of the WCF services, and doesn't succeed because of credentials ? Should I raise an event that forces all other modules to disconnect from their services, and then pop-up the 'Login' view ?

**Sorry for the long post ...**